# Prove that $\angle{CBM}=60^{\circ}-\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: geometry

> Given a $\triangle{ABC}$ with $\angle{BAC}=2\cdot \angle{ACB}=n^{\circ}$ where $0<n<120$, let $M$ be an interior point of $\triangle{ABC}$ with $BA=BM$ and $MA=MC$. Prove that $\angle{CBM}=60^{\circ}-\frac{n}{2}$.

**Attempt:**
[image]

We know that $\alpha+\beta = \angle{BAC} = n^{\circ}$ and that $$\angle{BAC}+\angle{ACB}+\angle{CBA} =\dfrac{3}{2}(\alpha+\beta)+\angle{CBA} = 180^{\circ}.$$ Also, $\angle{CBM} = \angle{CBA}-180^{\circ}+2\alpha$ and thus $$\dfrac{3}{2}(\alpha+\beta)+\angle{CBA} = \dfrac{3}{2}(\alpha+\beta)+\angle{CBM}+180^{\circ}-2\alpha =180^{\circ}$$ which means that $$\dfrac{3}{2}(\alpha+\beta)+\angle{CBM} = 2\alpha$$ and $$\angle{CBM} = \dfrac{1}{2}(\alpha-3\beta) = \dfrac{1}{2}(n-4\beta).$$ How do you continue from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Draw the line $BD$ parallel to $AC$ and choose $D$ such that $CD=BD$, then try to prove that $BMD$ is an equilateral triangle, then the solution will follow.

**Proof**

From the construction we have that $\angle BCD=\angle DBC= n/2$, hence 
$$\angle ACD=n/2+n/2=n= \angle BAC.$$

It follows that $ABDC$ is an isosceles trapeziod, then $AB=CD$. This implies that $ABM$ and $CMD$ are congruent triangles, in particular
$$CD=MD=MB=AB.$$
Fnally $BD=CD$ by construction, so
$$CD=MD=MB=AB=BD.$$

Comment: How does the solution follow?

Comment: Because then $\angle CBM=\angle MBD - \angle CBD=60 - n/2$.

Comment: Why does $\angle{CBD} = \dfrac{n}{2}$?

Comment: Because it is equal to $\angle ACB$ since $BD$ is parallel to $AC$.

Comment: Can you tell me how to prove it is equilateral?

Comment: @user19405892 I added a short proof.

Comment: How did you conclude that $\triangle{ABM} \cong \triangle{CDM}$? What angle did you use?

Comment: I used $\angle DCM=\angle MAB$.